# How can i make NSMutableArray only accept unique values?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *sectionTitles;
[sectionTitles addObject:due];
```

How do I just add unique values to an array?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**See Rudolph's Answer**

My old answer below is now outdated and has been for awhile. Rudoph's reference to `NSOrderedSet` / `NSMutableOrderedSet` is the correct one since these classes were added after this Q and my A.

**Old Answer**

As Richard said, `NSMutableSet` works well but only if you don't need to maintain an ordered collection. If you *do* need an ordered collection a simple content check is the best you can do:

```
if (![myMutableArray containsObject:newObject])
    [myMutableArray addObject:newObject];
```

*Update based on comment*

You can wrap this in a method like `-addUniqueObject:` and put it in an NSMutableArray [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html).

Comment: Also, as an additional note: it is not possible to create a subclass of NSMutableArray to add this functionality as NSMutableArray is a so-called class cluster: when you do `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` (or any variation) you will not get an instance of NSMutableArray but of some concrete class that implements the same interface.

Comment: That's what categories are for. :-) I have such a category for -addUniqueObject: on NSMutableArray.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1

Comment: See Rudolf's answer below for a more modern approach that did not exist at the time I answered this.

Answer (score 19):

More 2012-ish answer (in case someone stumbled upon this in the future):

Use `NSOrderedSet` and `NSMutableOrderedSet`.

A note about performance right from `NSOrderedSet` docs:

> You can use ordered sets as an alternative to arrays when the order of elements is important and performance in testing whether an object is contained in the set is a consideration— **testing for membership of an array is slower than testing for membership of a set**.

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSMutableSet`, it is best for these situations

[iOS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html)

[Mac OSX Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html)

Comment: @Yar: That's a huge assumption ya got there. NSMutableSet most certainly isn't the "right class" if you want to maintain an *ordered* collection (without adding an additional property to any model objects you want to contain in the set just for sorting by).

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi, good point, if you need ordering, you need an array.

Comment: You could use both, `NSMutableSet` for efficient membership queries and `NSMutableArray` for maintaining insertion order. It should be easy to encapsulate both in a single "OrderedSet" class (if you're targeting Lion, there is already `NSOrderedSet` for this purpose).

Comment: @omz: Good suggestion - that is indeed a nice new class for Lion and above.